# Changing Background image of Label on checked input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a CSS collapsible tree structure using the code from [this source](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu). I made some changes to remove the "+" and "-" images because it was throwing the formatting out of order, and decided to display the expanded part of the tree by using another folder image (one that's open), [like so](http://www.whitfield.k12.ga.us/?PN=DocumentUploads&L=0&DivisionID=%27%27&DepartmentID=%27%27&SubDepartmentID=%27%27&iRead=%27A%27&iAdd=%27A%27&iEdit=%27A%27&iDelete=%27A%27&LMID=%27820079%27&ClientModuleID=%2729543%27&TabNo=2).

I tried doing this in CSS using the ~ selector, but it doesn't work because the label is right before its associated input. I cannot switch it because then the tree won't expand/contract as expected.

I am exploring the possibility of using Javascript, but since I have around 300 label-checkbox pairs, it doesn't seem feasible to use getElementbyID to get the exact label I'm trying to fix. Is there an easier way to do this?

**HTML Code:**

```
<ol class="tree">
   <li>
      <label for="CB1">Label1</label><input type="checkbox" id="CB1" />
      <ol>
         <li class="file">File 1</li>
         <li class="file">File 2</li>
         <li class="file">File 3</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
ol.tree li.file a
    {
        background: url(../images/document.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        color: #2D629A;
        padding-left: 21px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
ol.tree li input
{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    top: 0;
}
ol.tree li label
{
    background: url(../images/folder-horizontal.png) 15px 1px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 37px;
}

ol.tree li input:checked ~ label
{
    background: url(../images/folder-open.png) 40px 5px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: you can achieve this by swapping them and using `+` (sibling) in css rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `<input>` element is in the wrong place.
It has to be **before** the label for it to work.

Second, for it to work properly, you need to set the `<ol>` to be hidden and then show it when the `<input>` is checked.

The resulting html:

```
<ol class="tree">
   <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="CB1" /><label for="CB1">Label1</label>
      <ol>
         <li class="file">File 1</li>
         <li class="file">File 2</li>
         <li class="file">File 3</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```

The new CSS:

```
ol.tree ol 
{
    display:none;
}
ol.tree li.file a
{
    background: url(../images/document.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    color: #2D629A;
    padding-left: 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
ol.tree li input
{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    top: 0;
}
ol.tree li label
{
    background: url(../images/folder-horizontal.png) 15px 1px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 37px;
}

ol.tree li input:checked ~ label
{
    background: url(../images/folder-open.png) 40px 5px no-repeat;
}

ol.tree li input:checked ~ ol
{
    display:block;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mjx8t596/1/

**Notice**:

I didn't touched on the images: I kept the same path and didn't changed any other thing in the code.

Comment: @dhishkaow You are welcome. I have done a project where I had to do something similar. You can use this code to make CSS3 menus (at least the mobile ones).